# Coordinate System Dependence

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In Spivak's book Calculus on Manifolds, he describes the definition of a coordinate system as being, given some $k$-manifold $M$, a 1-1 differentiable function $f: W \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is such that $f(W) = M \cap U$, $f'(u)$ has rank $k$ for each $y \in W$ and where $f^{-1}:f(W) \to W$ is continuous.

Now, there are several quantities that he is able to show are coordinate independent, such as the tangent space of $M$ at $x$, and also the unit normal vector $n(x)$.

I am stuck on an exercise that extends these concepts: Showing that $\det((g^{ij})(h_{ij}))$ is independent of the choice of coordinate, where it is defined that $(g^{ij}) = (g_{ij})^{-1} = (D_if \cdot D_jf)^{-1}$ and $(h_{ij}) = D_if \cdot D_jn$. Here, these $D_i$ are partial derivatives, $f$ is a coordinate system and $n$ is the unit normal vector to an oriented manifold $M$.

The unit normal $n(x)$ is defined as being the unique vector, given $f(0)=x$, which is equal to $f_*(v_0)$ for some $v_0 \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with $v^k < 0$.

I am not sure how to show such coordinate independence. I tried first expanding the determinant using rules of determinants of inverses, and when doing this I get stuck with a fraction involving determinant of the $h$ in the numerator and determinant of $g$ in the denominator. I am not sure how to proceed though, and further I'm not sure I see how this formula is coordinate independent. In particular, I don't see how to incorporate the unit normal vector into the proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So you’re talking about a unit normal in precisely what situation? In general, it makes no sense.

Comment: It's exactly as Spivak defines it. Given our coordinate system defined locally near $x$ with $x = f(0)$, then there exists some $v_0$ with $v^k < 0$ and we designate the normal vector to be $f_*(v_0)$; this is meant to be one of the two unit vectors in $M_x$ which are perpendicular to $(\partial M )_x$. So the question is to show that, given our local coordinate system $f$ around some $x \in M$, then the stated $\det$ is independent of any other (local) coordinates chosen. It is given these coordinates that we define the normal.

Comment: Notice you did not mention the boundary or orthogonality before.

Comment: The exercise with the determinant is a chain rule computation. You should take two different systems if coordinates and see how both $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ij}$ transform. In the quotient of two determinants, this transformation determinant will cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have two coordinate systems $y$ and $x = x(y)$. In $x$ coordinates we have the function $\phi(x) = \det(G(x)^{-1}Df(x)^TDn(x))$. In $y$ coordinates we set $\tilde{\phi}(y) = \det(\tilde{G}(y)^{-1}D\tilde{f}(y)^TD\tilde{n}(y))$. We are asked to show that $\phi(x) = \tilde{\phi}(y)$. Using formulas like $\tilde{f}(y) = f(x)$, $D\tilde{f}(y) = Df(x)Dx(y)$, it is straightforward to show that
$$\tilde{G}(y)^{-1}D\tilde{f}(y)^TD\tilde{n}(y) = Dx(y)^{-1}G(x)^{-1}Df(x)^TDn(x)Dx(y).$$
Using the product rule of the determinant, we obtain the result. Note that the above shows even that the linear transformation $G(x)^{-1}Df(x)^TDn(x)$ is coordinate independent when interpreted as a linear map from $T_{f(x)}M$ to $T_{f(x)}M$.

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick bit of clarification: I am slightly confused about how Spivak is defining coordinate systems. He made it seem like for every $x \in M$, we can find a coordinate transform $f$. So I assumed we would need to show, for instance, $\tilde{\phi}(x) = \phi(x)$, why do we do it for some other $y \in M$? Also, is there an assumption on $y$ that I am missing here? I'm not sure how to establish that for any two $x,y \in M$ we can have that there is a relation $x = x(y)$. Finally, for this question I assume we are taking $G(x) = Df(x) \cdot Df(x) ^T$?

Comment: I use $x$ and $y$ for points in open subsets of $H_k$, where $H_k = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^k : x_k \geq 0\}$. For $p \in \partial M$, there is your coordinate chart $f : W \to U \subset M$. Here $W$ is an open subset of $H_k$. Having another coordinate system $y$ means another coordinate chart $g : \tilde{W} \to U$, and we use the variable $y$ for points in $\tilde{W}$. The relations between the maps is $p = f(x) = g(y)$. The transition map from $y$ to $x$ coordinates is $x = f^{-1}(g(y)) : \tilde{W} \to W$, and is smooth by definition of manifold with boundary.

Comment: We are taking $G(x) = (g_{ij})(x) = Df(x)^TDf(x)$ for $x \in W$ and similarly, $\tilde{G}(y) = Dg(y)^TDg(y)$ for $y \in \tilde{W}$. Note the question is simply asking you to show how $G(x)^{-1}H(x) = G(x)^{-1}Df(x)^TDn(x)$ transforms. I suppose I could have used the variable $u$ instead of $x$ to match Spivak's notation.